# Struggling with Deep Linking Implementation in Expo React Native App

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, deep-linking, expo-linking

I'm facing difficulties implementing deep linking in my Expo React Native app. Despite configuring my app's navigation and handling incoming URLs as per the Expo documentation, I'm unable to navigate users directly to specific screens within the app using deep links. I've ensured that my app.json contains the necessary URL scheme configuration and have attempted to handle incoming URL intents in the app's entry point. However, the deep linking functionality still isn't working as expected. Any insights or solutions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using expo Linking package but still it's not working properly

Comment: **"ensure"** would not be helpful please provide minimal code to look at .

Comment: According to this documentations 
 https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/ i follow all step one by one but not working deep linking

Comment: When i click a link then how i open my app and after open how i get the query i have passed initially @Rainysidewalks